# Export of PATH not permanent

Tags: linux, path, export, global-variables, environment-variables

I'm using this command to export the path to use some packages I installed globally.

`export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

the problem is whenever I restart my machine, I would still need to export it again.

Is there a way to make this export permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, many a times that's the problem with doing `export PATH`.

You should append the environment variable directly into your **`.bash_profile`** file! This will be permanent and solve your purpose,thereby, making your package used globally without any further problem with the package's path.

Append the following to the end of your **`.bash_profile`** file,and replace the `~` with the actual path,i.e., **`/home/user_name`** :-

```
PATH=/home/user_name/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: @lozadaOmr- Yes, sorry I mis-typed. yes, put both the lines in the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: After I append it I got this when starting my terminal `bash: /home/omar/.composer/vendor/bin: Is a directory`

Comment: @lozadaOmr- Is composer a hidden directory? You should check the `.` before the directory composer. Also, check my edited answer to know how to do it!

Comment: @lozadaOmr- Check my final edit. It;ll resolve all of your errors!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your ~/.bash_profile:

`export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`